# What is the best way to use threads for database operations?

Tags: c#, sql, windows, multithreading, forms

I'm developing a WinForms application with SQL Compact as main database. I was told i would NEVER mess with the UI Thread, every operation needs to be done outside the UI Thread.. going by this speech for every CRUD operation I create a thread and a progress bar appears, but I think this might not be the best way to do this, and I'm quite unsure of where and when to use threads along side with database operations. I'm not using the UI Thread to make these DB calls but i'm not seeing any problems if i would. To show the information to the user i make Invokes when needed (to show data on a grid or a combobox). Here is a small piece of code:

```
this.SuspendLayout();

                ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog();


                Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(
                    new ThreadStart(() =>
                    {
                        var unitOfWork = new DAL.Implementations.Entity_Framework.UnitOfWork<dbgmEntities>();
                        var espacosRepository = unitOfWork.GetRepository<DAL.Espacos>();
                        Espacos espaco;

                        if (e.Row.Cells["ESP_Descr"].Value != null)
                            espaco = new Espacos { ESP_Nome = e.Row.Cells["ESP_Nome"].Value.ToString(), ESP_Descr = e.Row.Cells["ESP_Descr"].Value.ToString() };

                        else
                            espaco = new Espacos { ESP_Nome = e.Row.Cells["ESP_Nome"].Value.ToString() };


                        espacosRepository.AddOrAttach(espaco);
                        unitOfWork.Save();

                    }
              ));


                backgroundThread.Start();
                progressDialog.Show();
                progressDialog.Close();
                this.ResumeLayout();
```

I'm using Repository Pattern with SQL Compact and Entity Framework 4.0, as you can see i do database operations inside threads and not on the UI Thread which would block the user interface if it was a heavy operation.. the question is:

*Is it really necessary to make database calls from a thread outside the UI Thread or just a heavy operation? Like adding more than 1 or 2 rows on different tables.*

Thanks

Comment: re  _I was told i would NEVER mess_:  Those who use _never_ and _always_ are _usually_ wrong.

Comment: All absolutes are wrong, including this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI thread really should just be used to display things to the user and process input events from the user.  Anything else should be delgated to a worker thread.  That includes database operations.  The issue is that long-running processes tie up the main thread so that it is unable to do anything else for the duration of the process.  Since it's hard to guarantee that your database operation is going to come back quickly, it's probably not a good idea to have operations that access it be on the main thread.

Keep in mind that this is just a guideline.  If whatever work you're performing takes a very small amount of time, it's not worth it to spin up a new thread.  Spinning up a new thread costs you CPU cycles as well, so it might not be worth it to do that work on another thread.

**Some recommendations:**

- Don't instantiate threads directly; use the thread pool instead:  [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx)
- Don't immediately close your progress bar.  Show it, and then invoke the call to hide it from the worker thread after your database operation is complete.

[This is a good article on the thread pool.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm looking forward on that class.

Comment: Dan what about Smart Thread Pool? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool#_rating

Answer (score 0):

As Dan said, the UI thread *should* be used simply for displaying things and getting user input.

However, the vast majority of operations we tend to do are extremely fast.  To the point that spinning up another thread adds more to the time cost than simply performing the operation itself.  My suggestion is that you only spin up a new thread for anything which will take more than a few seconds to process.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this can be another alternative.